# Maven mvn --version on dos showing something special

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have installed apache maven 3.1 and when i check on dos i get this:

```
c:\>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 20:52:2
2+0530)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0-ea, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Last line should not be there. Is any thing wrong with my system or maven is not working as it should be?

Answer (score 1):

Add `C:\Windows\System32` to your Path variable in environment variables and try again